# C# version of optparse?

Tags: c#, command-line

Is there a C# port of the [optparse (command line option parser)](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-optparse.html) module from Python available under some [OSI-approved license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you already looked at http://csharpoptparse.sourceforge.net/ ?  I did not read the licensing, but since it it's on sourceforge, I would guess it is OSI approved.

Comment: It's released under an apache license, so it's OSI approved.

Answer (score 1):

CSharpOptParse homepage says it is a port of Perl's GetOpt, not of Python's optparse. Anyway, I looks terribly, unline the original optparse :/

Answer (score 0):

check NOptFunc at https://github.com/charlescook/noptfunc

Author blogged about it here when he started it..
http://cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000599.html